# UIWebView not loading external images

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I'm loading a UIWebView using the loadHTMLString method and depending on the connection speed, the images are sometimes not loaded and I just see a blank rectangle instead of the images. Has anyone seen this issue? Please note that the images are external links.

Comment: and the HTML string (maybe some images are relatively linked and you haven't set the baseURL)

Comment: external links means url?

Comment: if they are urls try make NSURLRequest of that link and use loadRequest method of webview

Comment: Please note that sometimes everything is loaded correctly, and sometimes isn't (same code, same HTML string).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to set your baseURL. How does your HTML img sections look like? Are you referencing the entire hyperlink including the http://? Make sure the full link is in there and you should have no problem. If you are referencing the images locally in your bundle you use:

```
NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"filename" ofType:@"html"];
NSString *HTMLData = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile];
[webView loadHTMLString:HTMLData baseURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]]];
```

Comment: I'm referencing the entire hyperlink. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, so it looks like a timeout. I don't need to set the baseURL because all the links are an external hyperlink, I assume...

Comment: ahhh, looks like the loading times. you can setup the UIWebView as a delegate, and have the webViewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad show and hide the webview control or show an activity indicator, like a busy indicator.

Comment: I have that, but sometimes it reaches webViewDidFinishLoad without loading the images.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:webUrl];

[self.WebView loadRequest:req];
```

if images are only external hyperlink

Comment: No, it's text with url images.